# Connecting ASP.NET MVC5 project to mysql database on godaddy

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a project which uses code first model and a mysql server at godaddy website. How can I connect Mysql database to asp.net ?
generating models from database is also fine but I am not able to do it in MySQL Database. Where as MS SQL works fine.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

{
    services.AddCors();

    services.AddDbContext<IronManContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddMvc();
}

In appsettings.json

{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=db;uid=root;password=***",
  }

}
```